# How to prevent scroll wheel on mobile but drag the map when tap on it?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my scenario:

I'm using a full width map with Google Maps Api, to prevent the scroll wheel on Desktop I've add the property: `scrollwheel:false` .

This works on Desktop but in Mobile I have some problems:
if I add the `draggable:false` I prevent the scroll wheel but I can't navigate and move the map (moreover the pan controll option is now deprecated).

How I can enable or disable the draggable map based on touch events?
In other words, how I can make the map usable on mobile?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem and came up with this. Although this may not be exactly what your looking for maybe you can make adjustments to fit your needs. If you tap on a mobile device the map will be draggable, when done dragging, tap again and it will lock it so you can move the mobile screen up and down again. Outside the map I give instructions to "click to drag map or not drag map" etc.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
   if (map.draggable) {
       this.setOptions({draggable:false});
   } else {
       this.setOptions({draggable:true});
   }
   if (map.scrollwheel) {
       this.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});
   } else {
       this.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
   }
});
```

Comment: Wow, bingo! This solve exactly my problem. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to add a vote for you. +1